# How do you delete an element from an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, co

I'm trying to make a program of choosing numbers and deleting arrays after.
How do I delete an element of an array in a code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int array[4];

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 24;
    array[2] = 34;
    array[3] = 100;

    for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the position you want to get rid of";
        cin>> array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Overwrite it with the next element. You could use a list. I recommend to use a STL container for this: vector, array, list, ...

Comment: What is a list? Is that in C++? I never learned about it

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: You should learn about the STL containers and stop using old style arrays.

Comment: You don't. Why do you think you want to? What are you trying to do? What's your _real_ question?

Comment: Future reference: the system says I voted to close this question as a duplicate. I did not. I voted to close it as unclear. The system is lying.

Comment: I use those arrays because that's how I learned and am expected to use them in my projects

Comment: whats does Error invalid conversion from int to char constant [f permissive] mean

Comment: @HelpME You should google the error message to see what information already exists online. If you still need help after searching, please post a new question.

Comment: You should learn about [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and the problem becomes trivial